# Is there good free media server for OS X to stream movies to an XBox 360?

Tags: macos, media, xbox360, upnp, media-server

I have a mac mini running OS X 10.5 that is filled with movies and I am looking for a good way to stream them to and Xbox 360?

Anyone have any suggestions for a media server (UPnP) for mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found two small apps for OS X that seem to handle what I am looking for, though they aren't free:

- [Rivet](http://cynicalpeak.com/rivet/) - exposed your iTunes, iPhoto, etc to an XBox360 and PS3
- [Connect360](http://www.nullriver.com/products/connect360) - exposes your iTunes, iPhoto, etc to an XBox360.

So far Rivet is working so well out of the box that I'm considering plunking down the $18 for it.

Comment: They may not be free, but they're the best I've found.  Rivet wins out over Connect360 due to the way it handles folders.  Connect360 flattens your filesystem (displays all media files in a single list), while Rivet allows you to browse by folder.

Comment: Old thread I know, but Rivet is now discontinued.

Answer (score 3):

I installed [Macports](http://www.macports.org/) for the Mac.

Once you successfully do this, install/port ushare, edit the config file with DIRS you wish to share, Xbox IP and Port. Then start streaming to your Xbox 360. :D

--You need to run ushare as a daemon, otherwise if you close the terminal running it the process will stop streaming :(

Comment: Also available via MacPorts, MediaTomb

Answer (score 2):

I use [XBMC](http://www.xbmc.org/) for both streaming from the network and streaming to the network, including my X-Box, MacBooks and Windows PC's. I do however have a dedicated media center setup using [TVersity](http://tversity.com/) for streaming as well.

Comment: TVersity looks good, but it is Windows only and I'm on a mac.  I'll give XBMC a try too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Vuze now supports XBOX 360 streaming (and it's free).  I'm simply not sure if the torrent aspect of the app will turn you off.  It's transcode algorithms are pretty good, in that it will convert the file on the fly, and using a wifi connection the XBOX detects the VUZE server easily.  It does flatten out folders however.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Amahi Home Server:](http://www.amahi.org)

> Amahi is software that runs on a dedicated PC as a central computer
>   for your home. It handles your entertainment, storage, and computing
>   needs. You can store, organize and deliver your recorded TV shows,
>   videos and music to media devices in your network. Share them locally
>   or safely around the world. And it's expandable with a multitude of
>   one-click install apps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both Rivet and Connect360. Rivet was better than Connect360 as it allowed videos to be organised in subdirectories, however it is now a discontinued product.

Occasionally my Xbox was unable to connect to my Macbook running either Connect360 or Rivet, so I tried [PS3 Media Server](https://code.google.com/p/ps3mediaserver/). Despite the deceptive name it works very well for streaming videos from OSX to Xbox360.I've had no problems with it after several months of use.